# Symfony2 form submit on related entity error

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem when submitting a from with a related entity. I get the following error message when submitting the form:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
My\ReportBundle\Entity\Clearance::setProjectProject() must be an instance of 
My\ReportBundle\Entity\Project, null given, called in
/var/www/Symfony/src/My/ReportBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on line 85 and 
defined in /var/www/Symfony/src/My/ReportBundle/Entity/Clearance.php line 272
```

The form builder code looks like this:

```
namespace My\ReportBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ClearanceType extends AbstractType
{


public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // Fields from the clearance entity removed ...
        // here is the problematic entry
        ->add('projectProject','entity',
         array('class'=>'My\ReportBundle\Entity\Project', 'property'=>'projectId'))
      ;
     }

      public function getName()
     {
         return 'my_reportbundle_clearancetype';
      }
```

And the controller contains this code:

```
     public function newclearanceAction()
     {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $id = $request->query->get('projectId');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $project = $em->getRepository("MyReportBundle:Project")->find($id);

    $clearance = new Clearance();
    $clearance->setProjectProject($project);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ClearanceType(), $clearance);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if($form->isValid()) {
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                    $em->persist($clearance);
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->
                    redirect($this->generateUrl('MyReportBundle_project_list'));
            }
         }
         return $this->render('MyReportBundle:Clearance:new.html.twig',
                 array('form'=>$form->createView()));
```

I don't have any idea how to fix this. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you post the form are you setting projectId in the query string?

If not try:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$clearance = new Clearance();

if($request->getMethod() != 'POST'){
    $id = $request->query->get('projectId'); 
    $project = $em->getRepository("MyReportBundle:Project")->find($id);
    $clearance->setProjectProject($project);
}
$form = $this->createForm(new ClearanceType(), $clearance);
```

The error is coming because you are not getting a project when you try and find one by id, thus when you try and set the project you are passing a null value through.

Comment: That was my problem! Thanks a lot :-)